# How to correctly use Partial views with Ajax Begin form

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I have the following code, in my index.cshtml

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
@using xx.Relacionamiento.Modelo.Bussiness.Entities;
@using xx.Relacionamiento.Modelo.Bussiness.Entities.Custom;

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

@model PresupuestosGenerale

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    }

<div class="">

    <div id="ContenedorPresupuestoGeneral">
        @Html.Partial("CreateOrEditPresupuestoGeneralxx", Model)
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
```

Then I have the following PartialView

```
@using xx.Relacionamiento.Modelo.Bussiness.Entities.Enumeraciones;
@using xx.Relacionamiento.Modelo.Bussiness.Entities;
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;


@model PresupuestosGenerale
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateOrEditPresupuestoGeneralxx", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "ContenedorPresupuestoGeneral", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(h => h.PresupuestoGeneralId)
            @Html.Hidden("Categoria",CategoriaEvento.xx.ToString())
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <label>Presupuesto Global xx</label>
                    <br />
                    @(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(e => e.PresupuestoGlobal)
                    .Decimals(0)
                    .DecreaseButtonTitle("Decrementar")
                    .IncreaseButtonTitle("Incrementar")
                    .Format("c0")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:99%;" })
                    .Max(1000000000000000000)
                    .Min(1)
                    .Step(100000)
                    .Placeholder("Presupuesto General xx"))
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(v => v.Valor, "", new { @style = "color: rgba(247, 20, 10, 0.97);" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary" value="Guardar Presupuesto" onclick="SetMostrarVentana();" />
                </div>
            </div>
        }


    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        MostrarVentanaLoading = false;
        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.MensajeError))
        {
            @:mostrarMensajeAlertGlobal("@ViewBag.MensajeError",15000)
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.MensajeSuccess))
        {
            @:mostrarMensajeAlertSuccessGlobal("@ViewBag.MensajeSuccess", 15000);
        }
    });

</script>
```

Then on my controller I have business logic that returns something different depending on conditions

```
 public ActionResult CreateOrEditPresupuestoGeneralxx(PresupuestosGenerale presupuestoGeneralxx)
        {
            try
            {
                ModelState.Remove("PresupuestoGlobal");

                if (presupuestoGeneralxx == null)
                {
                    return PartialView();
                }
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return PartialView(presupuestoGeneraxx);
                }

                if (presupuestoGeneralxx.Valor < 1)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Valor", "Por favor ingrese un presupuesto total");
                    return PartialView(presupuestoGeneralxx);
                }
```

So, when the user submits the form, the container from the index view is replaced with the new html.

The code works perfectly fine, however I feel that the code is ugly, not maintainable and difficult to read.

My questions, is, with asp.net mvc and ajax is there a better and more organized way to achieve the same thing with more readable code?

Comment: Why do you feel this is not maintainable?

Comment: it feels like ugly code. a view containing a partial view, which updates a div on the main view.

Comment: You Have written nice code if you want to make it maintainable then have proper comments on code you write to understand other

Comment: why have you split the view with a partial? just for ajax or any other reason?

Comment: The only thing that you might be able to improved is this line: ModelState.Remove("PresupuestoGlobal"); This is a comprehensive guide (where ModelState is not changed): pluralsight.com/guides/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would refactor the views moving the ajax form outside the partial. That way the full partial which is rendered inside the form is refreshed on ajax posts, keeps unaware and decoupled of container structure and every view has their own responsibility:

Index.cshtml

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateOrEditPresupuestoGeneralxx", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "form-content", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
        {
            <div id="form-content">
                @Html.Partial("CreateOrEditPresupuestoGeneralxx", Model)
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

CreateOrEditPresupuestoGeneralxx.cshtml

```
@using xx.Relacionamiento.Modelo.Bussiness.Entities.Enumeraciones;
@using xx.Relacionamiento.Modelo.Bussiness.Entities;
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;

@model PresupuestosGenerale

@Html.HiddenFor(h => h.PresupuestoGeneralId)
@Html.Hidden("Categoria",CategoriaEvento.xx.ToString())
<div class="row">
...
```

Comment: This is probably better than the original, but it then has a submit button in the partial but the form it submits is outside the partial. That seems a bit messy to me.

Comment: But that's not a problem. The role of the partial here is to let submit and redeaw form content through Ajax. The partial knows is a form content, but nothing about where the form is posted, if it's Ajax or not, etc, just know it's form content, and button is part of the form content

Comment: The submit button has an onclick event. Whether the form needs to know about more than the contents of the form itself depends on what that event does. But yes, you are almost certainly right.

Comment: I haven't noticed that, but now you pointed it, that's not a problem. First of all I wouldn't bind the event inside the markup but unobtrusively in document ready. This way you can decide if put event code as part of the partial, or in the container as form.submit. Maybe the second would be more clean, depending on what the event handler does

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the example that I used in some of my projects. In this example not only `PartialView` is rendered, also a `DropdownList` value is passed to the `PartialView` and displayed on it.

**View :**

```
<div id="divPartialView">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/MyPartialView.cshtml", Model)
</div>


$(document).ready(function () { 
    $(".SelectedCustomer").change(function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetPartialDiv", "Home")',
            data: { id: $(this).val() /*add other additional parameters */ },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                SetData(data);
            },
            error: function (data) { onError(data); }
        });
    });

    function SetData(data) {
        $("#divPartialView").html(data); //HTML DOM replace
    } 
});
```

**Controller :**

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult GetPartialDiv(int id /* ddl's selectedvalue */)
{
    Models.GuestResponse guestResponse = new Models.GuestResponse();
    guestResponse.Name = "this was generated from this ddl id:"; 
    return PartialView("MyPartialView", guestResponse);
}
```